# tensorflow-metal for Ubuntu VM -- Apple M2

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu, gpu, ros, apple-silicon

I have a MacBook Pro with an M2 chip. I am using TensorFlow to develop, train, and test a model. I would like to leverage tensorflow-metal for the GPU to speed up training. However, due to other software requirements, the training of the model MUST be done in Ubuntu 20.04, thus I have spun up a VM using Parallels.

How do I go about installing tensorflow-metal (or something similar) so I can use my GPU while training (on the Ubuntu VM)?

Version info:

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.10 (default, Mar 13 2023, 10:26:41) 
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> print(tf.__version__)
2.12.0
```

The software that requires me to use Ubuntu 20.04:

- ROS Noetic
- Gazeo 11
- PX4

I am also open to using PyTorch or trying to do something like run the ROS nodes on multiple OS's (not sure how to do that quite yet).

Comment: This will not work, as tensorflow-metal is built for MacOS, not for Linux. Probably the only solution is to train in a ubuntu server with a CUDA GPU.